# Execute master shell script using arguments

Tags: bash

I want to create one master shell script (`main.sh`) which will call 2 other child shell scripts (`install.sh` and `deploy.sh`)

`install.sh` -> can run simply as `./install.sh` OR `./install.sh -<arg_name>`

`deploy.sh` > can run simply as `./deploy.sh` OR `./deploy.sh -<arg_name>`

I know that I can use `source <path to shell script.sh>` command but how can I execute `install.sh -<arg_name>` from main script.

Example:
`./main.sh` should call `install.sh -k` if option `k` is provided.

Can anyone suggests the right approach to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass arguments with `"$@"`:

```
source install.sh "$@"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass arguments from the main script to the scripts you source. Example:

```
#!/bin/bash

source ./install.sh "$@"
source ./deploy.sh "$@"
```

This will pass all arguments to both scripts sourced. You then have to control the individual arguments within the sourced scripts.